# How can I type a command to execute when the current command completes?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command

I have a function (`not`) that displays a notification. Hence, I can use it to show when a command is complete.

```
sleep 5; not
```

However, sometimes I forget to add `;not`. In OS X's terminal (a few years ago), I could enter a second command, while the current command was running. This second command would execute after the first had finished.

Thus, I'd type `sleep 5`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then immediately type `not`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. After `sleep` had terminated, `not` would execute.

However, my experience in Linux is that this does not occur. After `sleep` terminates, the command line shows `not`, but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> never registers. I've tested Terminator, Konsole and a tty.

Is this behaviour dependent on the terminal emulator, and if so, are there any that work as I want? Alternatively, is there a way to make this function work in my terminal of choice (Terminator)?

## Testing in different shells

Doesn't work, i.e. the second command doesn't register:

- `bash`
- `bash --norc`
- `bash --norc --noprofile`
- `sh`

Does work, i.e. the second command registers:

- `bash --norc --noprofile --noediting`
- `zsh`

I selectively removed lines from `~/.inputrc` and tested with my default `bash` shell again. I traced the problem to the following line. When removed, the second command registers as expected.

```
Control-j: menu-complete
```

Oddly enough, if I try binding (say) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> instead, there is no problem. Why does this entry prevent the second command from registering, and is there a way to still use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> for `menu-complete` while having the behaviour that I want for this second command?

Comment: I've just checked in konsole. It works as you expected (enter is pressed).

Comment: @Jshura Thanks for that. I just tried again in konsole and it's definitely not working. FWIW I tried four iterations of `not<Enter>`, and got back `$ not notnotnot`(with that odd spacing). I get the same in Terminator.

Comment: which terminal and shell are you using? I've just checked with `gnome-terminal`, `xterm` and `tty` with `sh`, `bash` and `zsh`. All-time works for me

Comment: @Pandya I've tested with `terminator` and `konsole`, both with `bash`.

Comment: oh. `bash` is the problem. have a look at `man termios` and *`PENDIN`*.

Comment: @mikeserv This section says `not supported under Linux`? But it seems at least Pandya has it working with `bash`?

Comment: maybe pandya's kernel is built w/ those options or something.

Comment: This works in every shell/terminal combination that I've ever seen (for the `sleep` command, and generally almost all commands that don't read input for themselves — it may not work if the command does something to the terminal settings). The fact that this works is due to the fundamental mechanics of the terminal: input doesn't just disappear. Do you observe the same behavior with `bash --norc`? I suspect there's something in your configuration that explicitly discards pending input.

Comment: @Gilles No, even with `bash --norc` it fails.

Comment: @mikeserv Possibly? I'm just using the latest stock kernel under Arch.

Comment: @Gilles I traced it to a line in `~/.inputrc`, and I've edited the question.

Comment: Ctrl+j is <newline>.

Comment: @mikeserv Ahh… so presumably when another command is executing, `<Enter>` sends `^j`, which is *not* interpreted as a newline, hence the problem. However, this still begs the question of why `<Enter>` works at all in the first place, when there is not another command running. (Regardless, I presume there is no workaround if I want to rebind `^j`.)

Comment: Its because `readline` reads non-canonical input - essentially raw - and switches the terminal back to canonical state while other commands run. So `\r`eturns are not translated in real-time and `readline` interprets those as newlines - but when the terminal is in a canonical state the `\r`eturns are translated to newlines. Maybe look at `stty -icrnl`.

Comment: Also try `bash -i <<<$'echo hey\recho there'` then the same thing again w/ `bash --noediting` to see what I mean about `bash` and returns.

Comment: @mikeserv Okay thanks, that makes sense. Good advice on `stty -icrnl`; that works now. I searched, but still don't really understand what it does, or potential pitfalls/negatives. Could you please make it an answer, and flesh out these details?

Comment: @mikeserv Okay, so one [pitfall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline/454663) is that `read` won't work anymore.

Comment: oh man, i forgot about this. well... it will. but not from terminal input as terminated by newlines. in bash there's `read -d $'\r'` - which works out to much the same - but you'll also want `read() if [ -t 0 ]; then command read -d $'\r' "$@"; else command read "$@"; fi`. Honestly, its weird to me that you don't use newlines with CTRL+J, though. I do it all the time. Do CTRL+V then CTRL+J and see what I mean.

Comment: I edited and undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to some of your edits you've got `CTRL+J` bound to a `bindkey` macro command. That explains your `bash` issue considering `readline`'s default behavior.

Generally `readline` reads input in something very like `stty raw` mode. Input chars are read in as soon as they are typed and the shell's line-editor handles its own buffering. `readline` sets the terminal to raw when it takes the foreground, and it restores it to whatever its state was beforehand when calling up another foreground process group.

`CTRL+J` is an ASCII newline. `ABCDEFGHIJ` is 10 bytes from NUL. Because you have configured `readline` to eat this character and subsequently to expand away what remains of any command-line on which it does with menu-completion, type-ahead won't work. The terminal is in a different state when the type-ahead is buffered by the kernel's line-discipline than it is when `readline` is in the foreground.

When `readline` is in the foreground it does its own translation for input carriage returns -> newlines and the terminal driver doesn't convert it at all. When you enter your type-ahead input, though, the terminal driver will typically translate returns to newlines as can be configured with `stty [-]icrnl`. And so your return key is sufficient for commands entered live, but the newlines sent by the terminal's line-discipline are being interpreted as menu-complete commands.

You might tell the terminal driver to stop this translation with `stty -icrnl`. This is likely to take at least a little bit of getting used to. Other commands that accept terminal input will usually expect newlines rather than returns, and so you'll either have to explicitly use `CTRL+J` when they control the foreground, or else teach them to handle the returns as `bash` does.

You've already mentioned that `read` doesn't work as expected when reading form the terminal. Again, it likely would if you explicitly used `CTRL+J` to end an input line. Or... you can teach it:

```
read()
    if    [ -t 0 ]
    then  command read -d $'\r' "$@"
    else  command read "$@"
    fi
```

It will probably be a lot less hassle in the long-run if you found a different key for menu-complete, though. Newlines are kind of a big deal for most terminal applications.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using bash: Try hitting ^Z (i.e., Ctrl-Z) to stop the
process, move it to the background, and get another bash prompt.  Type
`fg; not`, the former continues the stopped process and returns when
it finishes.

Alternatively, figure out the proces id of the program you want to
wait for, assume it's 2342.  In a new shall, type

```
until kill -0 2342; do sleep 1; done; not
```

this will check every second.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but Ctrl+z doesn't always work. For example, if my command is `sleep 5; echo foo`, `sleep` is suspended but the `echo` runs immediately. Or if it's running a `for` loop, the loop seems to just terminate. Similarly, the second suggestion will fail for chained commands and pipes.